# EF Core 7 : problem with saving two entities at the same time

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I'm using EF Core 7 and have problems saving my models. I have two models with a 1:n relation:

```
public class BetriebDto : EntityBase
{    
    // ...

    public IList<MeldesatzDto>? Meldesaetze { get; set; }
}

public class MeldesatzDto : EntityBase
{
    public required BetriebDto Betrieb { get; set; }

    // ....
}
```

Note that both models inherit from `EntityBase` which defines an `Id` as `Guid`.

In my scenario I get a kafka event to save one `Betrieb` and one `Meldesatz`.

My code for saving looks something like this:

```
betriebEntity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
await _DbContext.AddAsync(betriebEntity);
await _DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

meldesatzEntity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
meldesatzEntity.Betrieb = betriebEntity;        
await _DbContext.AddAsync(meldesatzEntity);
await _DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

With this code, I get this error on the last call to `SaveChangesAsync`:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: d802d14d-c748-41e2-a7ec-c8d476a719a6

Note that this Guid belongs to my `betriebEntity`. I guess that EF tries to save the `Betrieb` a second time while saving the `meldesatz`.

What is the best practise to save two entities that depend on each other in one run?

Comment: It's enough to add the `meldesatzEntity` only.

Comment: Unless you need something from saving the first entity (any auto generated column), use the second save only.

Comment: Can you please show how exactly your code looks.